# Force intercept at origin with scipy.stats.pearsonr or alternatives?

Tags: scipy, pearson-correlation

I checked the documentation of [scipy.stats.pearsonr](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html) but did not find any options to force intercept at origin `0,0`.

If it's impossible with `scipy.stats.pearsonr` does anyone know any alternatives?

Comment: Is there an example of something that does what you're looking for in another programming language? I would understand what you mean if this were about `linregress`, but not `pearsonr`. What is the null hypothesis you want to test?

Comment: Your are probably confused with coefficient of Determination which involve the model hence can be affected by the existence of intercept in the model. Person coefficient is uniquely defined and non parametric hence it has no model or concept of intercept. It compares covariance and variances.

Answer (score 1):

> I checked the documentation of `scipy.stats.pearsonr` but did not find any options to force intercept at origin `0,0`.

The Pearson correlation coefficient has the property that you can add any number to either sample, or multiply either number by a non-negative number, and this won't change the calculated R score.

For example, if you compare a sample to the same sample plus 10, it still has a correlation of 1.0 with the original.

```py
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
import numpy as np


a = np.array([0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34])
b = a + 10
print(pearsonr(a, b))
```

I assume what you're asking for is a version of Pearson's correlation coefficient where being wrong by a constant does matter. Scikit-learn has something similar to this.

Example:

```py
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
import numpy as np


a = np.array([0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34])
b = a + 10
print(r2_score(a, b))
```

In this example, being wrong by a constant does matter, and it gets a R^2 of 0.087.

You should be aware of four gotchas about this:

1. The `r2_score()` function is affected by both scaling the sample and adding a constant. In other words, `r2_score(a, a * 2)` will be a score less than 1.0.
2. This is R^2, not R.
3. This score is in the range (-∞, 1]. A score of 1.0 means a perfect match. A score of 0.0 means that it is as accurate a match as predicting the mean of the input distribution for every point. Unlike `pearsonr()`, -1 does not mean that it is perfectly negatively correlated. Instead, a negative score means that it is worse than predicting the mean, and it can be infinitely negative, because it can be infinitely worse.
4. Unlike Pearson correlation, this score is not symmetric. In other words, `r2_score(a, b)` is not necessarily the same thing as `r2_score(b, a)`.

See the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html) for more.